# Python Classes - pushing down variable names through functions

Tags: python, class

I'm new to classes, but trying to make an effort to incorporate them into programs for functions that all take the same inputs (I'm assuming that's when doing it makes the most sense...?). I'm working on a chess board, so it seems fitting.

I have an example below where I'm trying to pull in the valid moves for a piece.

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self, board, r, c):
        self.board = board
        self.r = r
        self.c = c

    def piece(self): 
        return self.board[self.r,self.c]

    def color(self):
        #does this line not get pushed down so 'legal_moves' can't see self.piece?
        self.piece = Board(self.board,self.r,self.c).piece()

        if self.piece == '-':
            return 'N'
        elif self.piece.istitle():
            return 'w'
        else: 
            return 'b'

#This is the function that returns None
     def legal_moves(self):

     moves = {'P':[(1,0)],
                   'p':[(-1,0)],
                   'r':[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)],
                   'n':[(2,1),(2,-1),(-2,-1),(-2,1)], 
                   'b':[(1,1),(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1)],  
                   'k':[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1),(1,1),(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1)]}

    return moves.get(self.piece)
```

My board is just a standard 8x8 chess board with R-K for 'w' and r-K for 'b' in its initial configuration (no moves made)

```
print(Board(curr,1,2).piece())  #returns P - correct
print(Board(curr,1,2).color())  #returns w - correct
print(Board(curr,1,2).legal_moves()) #returns None - incorrect
```

Thank you! Also, I'm new to programming so if you have any style/efficiency comments, please add them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're calling `get` on `self.piece` which is your method, not the *result* of the method. This key isn't in your dict and you get default value of `get`

You need:

```
moves.get(self.piece())
```

Maybe making `piece` a *property* using the property decorator would be more readable (and you wouldn't need the `()`)

```
@property
def piece(self): 
    return self.board[self.r,self.c]
```

with that `moves.get(self.piece)` works.

Comment: Thanks very much! Perfect. As a side note, should I be able to define `def valid_move(self,r,c,r_offset,): self.r_offset, self.c_offset = r+r_offset, c+c_offset` and then use `self.r_offset` in other functions within the same class? It seems like no, but just wanted to double check